# Access the Visual Studio "Find all references"-API

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

In Visual Studio you can search for each method reference by rightclicking > "Find all references".

I am wondering if I can access these Windows-API. I want to analyze my solutions and projects.
My goal is to implement an addon for VS so I can easily search for method-references in other solutions/projects which reference a certain project AND really use the method.

Maybe where is something in the EnvDTE namespace?